# Cocoa NSScrollView not scrolling

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

I try to create a scrollview. Created a scrollview via Xib, programmatically added scrolledView (a NSView that contains all subview in scrollView).

The following code shows the subviews but the scrollView not scroll. Why?

```
class LevelScrollController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet var scrollView: NSScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scrolledView = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: 300))

    // Inserisco pulsanti di esempio
    for i in 1 ... 10{
        scrolledView.addSubview(NSButton(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: i*30, width: 100, height: 30)))
    }
    scrollView.addSubview(scrolledView)
}
```

Putting the code in viewDidLayout instead of viewDidLoad not change the result: not scroll

Answer (score 6):

Instead of add scrolledView to subview of scrollView, set it as documentView.

Replace `scrollView.addSubview(scrolledView)` with `scrollView.documentView = scrolledView`